# Почему root шлёт сообщения root?

Tags: linux, freebsd, postfix

Почему root шлёт сообщения root?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто ему скучно :) запускайте то что шлёт вам сообщение от другого пользователя, для разнообразия, и это не совсем правильно что бы сервисы работали под нутом.

Answer (score 2):

во-первых, сообщение шлёт не пользователь `root`, а программа, выполняющаяся, вероятно, от имени этого пользователя.

во-вторых, шлёт сообщение не пользователю `root`, а по адресу `root@...`. а куда уже почтовый сервер сохранит или перенаправит сообщение — зависит от текущих настроек сервера и от содержимого (почти конфигурационных) файлов (типа [`/etc/aliases`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_alias), [`.forward`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ru/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.networkcomm/mail_forwardfiles.htm) и т.д. и т.п.), которые в этих настройках указано принимать к сведению.

---

*для чего вообще высылается сообщение?* чтобы его мог прочитать человек (или какая-нибудь программа, занимающаяся обработкой таких сообщений), у которого есть доступ к тому хранилищу сообщений, куда в конце концов данное сообщение попадёт.

*почему именно по такому адресу: `root@...`*? в первую, вероятно, очередь — для простоты администрирования. если бы разные программы отсылали бы сообщения по разным адресам, администратору приходилось бы либо просматривать множество хранилищ сообщений, либо добавлять множество правил пересылки, чтобы сообщения «стекались» в одно (два-три-сколько-надо) место.